# SSRS Visual studio 2015 BIDS system.outofmemoryexception

Tags: visual-studio, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I have a simple BIDS report project with a simple SQL. that supposed to show 922 rows of data. 
the interactive size of the report. is 8.5 x 11.

But when I preview it, it shows error that says system.outofmemoryexception.

Any advise how to fix this? is it something to do with the server even when I preview in my local computer?

Spec of the PC: quad core 3.19 Ghz
64 bit windows 10 pro
8GB of RAM
virtual paging size is set at 1.2GB

ssrs server is running SQL 2012

when I monitor the task manager, it ran for about 30 seconds. ram barely increasing and it's got plenty of free ram when it error out.
screenshot below

[image]

this is the error I see

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Increase virtual memory page file from 1.2GB to 3GB and seems to be working now